# Frame not being set with initWithFrame with xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am having huge problems with learning autolayout especially when integrating xibs and uiscrollviews. In an effort to simplify my problem, I started a new project with a single view tied to a storyboard. I then subclassed UIView (`Diptic`) and created a xib file for it. My storyboard is not using autolayout, but my Diptic xib is. Right now I want to have a horizontal scrollView with a few Diptic instances layed out across it. But I am only ever getting the first diptic instance to show up, because the frame isn't being initialized correctly.

In my ViewController.m's viewDidLoad:

```
 self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width+10)*5, self.view.frame.size.height);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int x = i*(self.view.frame.size.width+10);
        Diptic *diptic = [[Diptic alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:diptic];
        [array addObject:diptic];

        UIView *greenBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 5, 40, 40)];
        greenBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:greenBox];
    }
```

Diptic.m

```
#import "Diptic.h"
@implementation Diptic
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Diptic" owner:nil options:nil];
        self = [views objectAtIndex:0];
        self.label.text = @"WOOT";
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

If I set the frame after I add it to the view it seems to work, but why can't I set the frame with `initWithFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you assign the frame to a view that is created with a call to `[super initWithFrame:frame]`. When the NIB is loaded in `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`, `self` is replaced with a view from `[views objectAtIndex:0]` and the frame for this view is never set. Instead, eliminate the call to `super` and load the view from the NIB instead:

```
#import "Diptic.h"
@implementation Diptic

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Diptic" owner:nil options:nil];
    self           = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    if (self) {
        self.frame           = frame;
        self.label.text      = @"WOOT";
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Cannot assign self outside of a method of the init family. And you are right, initWithFrame isn't called from the xib. It is called when I call it in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

When init a view/controller from storyboard or from xib, the init method is

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

try to do other things in this method